# What angle should I cut a miter joint at? vs. At what angle should I cut a miter joint?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm watching this video [here](https://youtu.be/pP4acHxygqk?t=211) and was wondering -- why is "What angle should I cut a miter joint at?" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Because you haven't specified the angle of the corner being mitered.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on the rules regarding this.

Comment: Some people (I am an example) will tell you never to end a clause with a preposition, but is has become acceptable to do so. This is a matter of style, not of grammar, so either way is correct.

Comment: I like "cut a joint at," people talk that way, but it invites ridicule. "At what angle" solves one problem and creates an unlovable flow that is politically correct. How did we get here? By backing ourselves into a corner. We have other choices: What angle do I need for cutting the miter joint (or for mitering the joint)?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya A preposition is a terrible thing with which to end a sentence.  Just rolls off the tongue, doesn't it?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

There was, at one time, a serious prohibition against putting a preposition *after* its object.  This came, according to the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/), from Latin where "the rule is that a preposition should always *precede* the prepositional object that it is linked with: it is never placed after it."

But Oxford also notes several instances where it is more natural to put the preposition after its object: passive structures, relative clauses, infinitive structures, and some questions.

So, really, it's up to you and what sounds best.  [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/youve-been-lied-to-heres-why-you-absolutely-can-end-a-sentence-with-a-preposition/) does note that it is more casual to end a sentence with a preposition.

I will note that, unless things get really unwieldy, I avoid putting the preposition after its object -- your example of *at what angle should I cut a miter joint?* seems perfectly natural to me and even one of the Oxford Dictionaries examples -- *Tom had no-one to play with* would, in my opinion, be better as *Tom had no-one **with whom** to play*.

Hope this helps.